# how to convert Java Instant for showing Date in the angular client side?

Tags: javascript, java, angular, typescript, nativescript

I use java spring-boot in the server and use `Instant.now()` for fill `Instant` date variable.

In my client, I want to show the date but its format is `UTC` that look like this :

```
"date": "2018-09-11T11:16:27.708783700Z"
```

I am using `NativeScript` and `Angular` on my client how should I format this date on my client?

Comment: Unix Timestamps are a great way of sharing dates between two systems, as they do not rely on a certain format, try those.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular have built in [date pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#pre-defined-format-options)

```
setDateTime(dateTime) {
    let pipe = new DatePipe('en-US');

    const time = pipe.transform(dateTime, 'mediumTime', 'UTC');

    const date = pipe.transform(dateTime, 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'UTC');

    return date + ' ' + time;
  }
```

html

`<span>{{dateTime| date:'MM/dd/yyyy' : 'UTC'}}</span>`

Comment: and how can I change TimeZone to Tehran that is (GMT+4:30)?

Answer (score 0):

For client side you can use angular `date` pipe API to make it readable date. Or else you can also use [moment](https://momentjs.com/).
Below is the sample

```
@Component({
 selector: 'date-pipe',
 template: `<div>
   <p>Today is {{today | date}}</p>
   <p>Or if you prefer, {{today | date:'fullDate'}}</p>
   <p>The time is {{today | date:'h:mm a z'}}</p>
 </div>`
})
// Get the current date and time as a date-time value.
export class DatePipeComponent {
  today: number = Date.now();
}
```

You can look at their docs [here](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#datepipe)

Comment: this is for angularjs, not angular, they arent the same

Comment: @mast3rd3mon sorry misread the question. thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Mind removing the downvote now ?